# When not to use integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to evaluate this [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861230/the-integral-int-0-infty-dfracx-sinxx21-dx#861230) using integration by parts.

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g'(x)dx,$$
where $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g'(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$. So: $f'(x)=\cos x$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\log(1+x^2)$.

Therefore:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}I=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g'(x)dx&=\left[f(x)g(x)\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}f'(x)g(x)dx,\\&=\left[\dfrac{1}{2}\log (1+x^2)\sin x\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2}\log(1+x^2)\cos x\,dx}_{\text{another integration by parts}},\\&=\left[\dfrac{1}{2}\log (1+x^2)\sin x\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\left[-\log (1+x^2)\sin x\right]_{0}^{\infty}+\\2\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin x\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}dx}_{I}\right)\\&=\left[\log (1+x^2)\sin x\right]_{0}^{\infty}-I.\end{split}\end{equation}$$

Thus, 
$$I=\left[\dfrac{1}{2}\log (1+x^2)\sin x\right]_{0}^{\infty}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{2}\log (1+x^2)\sin x.$$

**My question is:** Whatever I did a mistake or not (of course I would like to know also), I would like to know what are the conditions to use integration by parts. Is it always allowed?

Comment: You did make a mistake; you have a sign wrong on the second integration by parts (in fact, the sign is wrong on both terms), and you will get $0=0$ I think, which is not too helpful :) In answer to your question, integration by parts is always valid assuming the component functions are reasonable, but it will not always be useful, nor can you always carry it through to get an answer in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/861230/15941)

Comment: "Evaluation" of $\frac{1}{2}\log(1+x^2)\sin x$ "at $\infty$" does not make sense.

Comment: I thought it is $\infty$ @AndréNicolas

Comment: It is quite unsafe to treat the symbol $\infty$ as if it were a number. For example, let $n$ be vary large, and let $x=n\pi$. Then $\sin x=0$, and therefore $\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)\sin x=0$. Or else imagine $x$ very large, but such that $\sin x=-1$. Then $\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)\sin x$ is  large negative.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it.

Comment: By the way, the definite integral you started with does converge, and can be evaluated exactly using tools from complex variables. What is the original question you were asked?

Comment: I was trying to answer this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/861230/15941) and I tried integration by parts by I found that it does not make sense. So I thought that maybe integration by parts cannot be used everywhere. Then I asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @rogerl's comment, integration by parts holds when $f$ and $g$ are [regular and of finite variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration#Integration_by_parts). For an example of why it is *not* sufficient for $f$ and $g$ to just be differentiable, see [this reference.](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Kheifets-MMz-201030891.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Your second integration by parts has an extra minus sign.

Overall, what you are trying to do wouldn't yield anything useful, because you write essentially this:

$$\int fg' = [fg]-\int f'g = [fg]- \left([fg]-\int fg'\right).$$

So unless you suddenly can produce an antiderivative of $\ln (1+x^2)$, your double integration by parts doesn't help.